# how do I write lines to a NamedTemporaryFile then print each line

Tags: python, zip, temporary-files

I'm trying to unzip a zip file containing a csv file and write all the rows from the csv file into a NamedTemporaryFile. Then print the lines from the temp file to ensure that it has written the desired lines properly. This is my current code which when the "print(line)" is called returns a blank.

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(file_name) as zip_fp:
        for item in zip_fp.namelist():
            temp_file = NamedTemporaryFile()
            with zip_fp.open(item) as fp:
                with open(temp_file.name, mode='wb+') as temp_fp:
                    temp_fp.writelines(fp.readlines())
                    for line in temp_fp:
                        print(line)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `temp_fp.writelines(fp.readlines())` has written all the lines to the file and the cursor is now at the end of file so you wont get anything. Try out the below code (last 3 lines are added to your code):

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(file_name) as zip_fp:
        for item in zip_fp.namelist():
            temp_file = NamedTemporaryFile()
            with zip_fp.open(item) as fp:
                with open(temp_file.name, mode='wb+') as temp_fp:
                    temp_fp.writelines(fp.readlines())
                with open(temp_file.name, mode='r') as temp_fp:
                    for line in temp_fp:
                        print (line)
```

OR - `seek` to the start of file and read all the line:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(file_name) as zip_fp:
        for item in zip_fp.namelist():
            temp_file = NamedTemporaryFile()
            with zip_fp.open(item) as fp:
                with open(temp_file.name, mode='wb+') as temp_fp:
                    temp_fp.writelines(fp.readlines())
                    # SEEK TO START OF FILE
                    temp_fp.seek(0,0)
                    for line in temp_fp:
                        print (line)
```

Comment: Both of these answers keep the zipfile open when there is no need to do so.  Additionally the firs is wrong as it opens the file in *write* mode, not read

Comment: Oops, a copy-paste, anyways updated second part to open file in read mode

Comment: No Problem :-) Glad that I could help!

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that writing seeks to the end of the file, so there's nothing left to read.  This code:

```py
with zip_fp.open(item) as fp:
     with open(temp_file.name, mode='wb+') as temp_fp:
         temp_fp.writelines(fp.readlines())
             for line in temp_fp:
                 print(line)
```

Does the following:

- open the zip as fp:
- open the tempfile as temp_fp
- write from the beginning of temp_fp (since we are not in append mode).
- read anything after the end of the file (i.e. nothing).

There is no reason to check that writing has worked: it will.  However, if you wanted to do it, something like this would work:

```py
with zip_fp.open(item) as fp, temp_file.open("wb+") as tmpf:
    for line in fp:
        tmpf.writelines([line])
with tmp_file.open("rb") as tmpf:
    for line in tmpf:
        print(line)
```

Note a few fixups here---using path objects all the way through, multiple withs in one line, and avoiding ram wastage by writing straight away.

Incidentally should these be binary mode?